# SharePoint REST API Online batch request issues : getting 400 Bad Request, odata.error Invalid request

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, batch-request

I'm having a bit of trouble isolating a batch request using the _api/$batch request. I'm sure there is just some simple mistake/issue going on, but I can't just pinpoint this.  Any ideas?

Here are some snippets of the raw postman console logs for the request:

```
POST /_api/$batch HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json; odata=nometadata
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="batch_8215457c-c4fb-432a-abf6-7b1f86168c65"
Authorization: Bearer <token deleted>

--batch_8215457c-c4fb-432a-abf6-7b1f86168c65
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="changeset_d9097ba9-2d69-40ca-a301-90cf97aafb17"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

--changeset_d9097ba9-2d69-40ca-a301-90cf97aafb17
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

DELETE https://myOrg.sharepoint.com/sites/mySite/_api/web/lists/getByTitle(myList)/items(27) HTTP/1.1
If-Match: *
Accept: application/json; odata=nometadata

--changeset_d9097ba9-2d69-40ca-a301-90cf97aafb17
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

DELETE https://myOrg.sharepoint.com/sites/mySite/_api/web/lists/getByTitle(myList)/items(30) HTTP/1.1
If-Match: *
Accept: application/json; odata=nometadata

--changeset_d9097ba9-2d69-40ca-a301-90cf97aafb17--

--batch_8215457c-c4fb-432a-abf6-7b1f86168c65--
```

The response I get back for each item to be deleted is 400 Bad Request with each Batch response also containing:
{"odata.error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Invalid request."}}}

```
--batchresponse_38add954-a201-4857-a6db-68067eb9bc0a
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
CONTENT-TYPE: application/json;odata=nometadata;streaming=true;charset=utf-8

{"odata.error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Invalid request."}}}
--batchresponse_38add954-a201-4857-a6db-68067eb9bc0a
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
CONTENT-TYPE: application/json;odata=nometadata;streaming=true;charset=utf-8

{"odata.error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Invalid request."}}}
--batchresponse_38add954-a201-4857-a6db-68067eb9bc0a--
```

I've been digging and have tried a few things:

- Tried removing the "Accept: application/json; odata=nometadata" from each changeset
- Tried adjusting any newlines after requests content-type/encoding
- I have tried executing one item in the batch as a single delete request (works)
- compared some notes/examples: (Andrew Connell blog: https://gist.github.com/andrewconnell/dcd89e694475b628d0c7)

Can a helpful eye point out the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bad interpretation of the documentation on my part.

According to [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/make-batch-requests-with-the-rest-apis?redirectedfrom=MSDN#sectionSection0), the section on the Request URL states (emphasis mine):

> The request URL consists of the **root service URL** and the `$batch` option; for example, https://fabrikam.sharepoint.com/_api/$batch or https://fabrikam.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/$batch.

However, the "root service URL" is a bit misleading, as it's actually supposed to be the *site's* URL. I would have considered the root service URL:

```
https://myorg.sharepoint.com
```

So, in my example above, it's:

```
POST <siteURL>/_api/$batch
```

Or, more specific to the example:

```
POST https://yourorg.sharepoint.com/sites/mySite  HTTP/1.1
```

Thanks for everyone who put some thought into this.